# applescript elements, classes, and objects

Tags: collections, applescript

I'm writing an applescript to automate some tedious work in Aperture, and I'm having a hell of a time understanding some of the peculiarities of the language. In particular, I'm having a really difficult time dealing with collections (lists and elements). I'm stumped by object specifiers that include collections and applying commands to elements in a collection. Moreover, I'm confused by strange differences in object specifiers that seem to behave differently when referring to object elements by their class within a class versus, well, let me show you.

Here's the beginning of a script.

```
prop Movies : {}

tell Application "Aperture"
     set Movies to every image version whose name of every keywords contains "Movie"
end tell

length of Movies   -- result => 601
```

The `application` object in Aperture contains an elements collection of `image version`s. `image version` objects contain an elements collection of `keyword`s. `keyword`s are objects/lists with a `name` and `id` property.

So the global script property `Movies` now contains all of the `image version` objects in my Aperture library that are actually videos. Now, when I try to do this:

```
repeat with movie in Movies
    log ("Movie name is '" & name of movie & "'.")
    log ("  the class of this object is '" & class of movie & "'.")
end
```

the output, as expected, is:

```
Movie name is 'MOV03510.MPG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
Movie name is 'MOV00945'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
Movie name is 'MOV03228.MPG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
Movie name is 'MOV02448'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
...
```

However, I'm stuck with how to access an elements collection within those `image version`s. When I do this:

```
repeat with movie in Movies

    log ("Movie name is '" & name of movie & "'.")
    log ("  the class of this object is '" & class of movie & "'.")
    set kwnamelist to name of every keyword in movie
    if kwnamelist contains "Movie"
       log ("    Yes, '" & name of movie & "' is indeed a video.")
    end if
end
```

gives me

```
find_videos.applescript:1089:1096: script error: Expected class name but found identifier. (-2741)
```

The error, to me, sounds like applescript is confused by the object specifier `name of every keyword in movie`. BUT, the reason I'm so confused about this is that if I write this code:

```
tell Application "Aperture"
    repeat with imageind from 1 to 1000
        set img to item imageind of image versions
        tell me to log ("Image name is '" & name of img & "'.")
        tell me to log ("  the class of this object is '" & class of img & "'.")
        set kwnamelist to name of every keyword in img
        if kwnamelist contains "Movie" 
            tell me to log ("    '" & name of img & "' is actually a video!")
        end if
    end
end tell
```

then I get the expected output:

```
...
Image name is 'DSC_4650'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
Image name is '104-0487_IMG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
Image name is 'MOV02978.MPG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
    'MOV02978.MPG' is actually a video!
Image name is '108-0833_IMG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.

...
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my object specifier? Why is it that I can essentially apply `get name` to `every keyword in img` when the `image version` is in one context, but I can't in a different context? Is there something I'm missing here? Is it that the `keyword` class is internal to the Aperture `application` object? How would I specify something like `application::keyword` if that's the case?

UPDATE:

I've *solved* this particular problem, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain exactly why this *solves* it. I did this:

```
tell Application "Aperture"
    repeat with movie in Movies
        tell me to log ("Movie name is '" & name of movie & "'.")
        tell me to log ("  the class of this object is '" & class of movie & "'.")
        set kwnamelist to name of every keyword in movie
        if kwnamelist contains "Movie"
            tell me to log ("    Yes, '" & name of movie & "' is indeed a video.")
        end if
    end
end tell
```

gives the expected output:

```
...
Movie name is 'IMG_0359'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
    Yes, 'IMG_0359' is indeed a video.
Movie name is 'MOV02921.MPG'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
    Yes, 'MOV02921.MPG' is indeed a video.
Movie name is 'MOV02249'.
  the class of this object is 'image version'.
    Yes, 'MOV02249' is indeed a video.
...
```

It seems like there's a very peculiar scope issue at work here. Could someone explain to me how `keyword` objects are in scope in this new version, but out of scope in the previous version where we weren't in a `tell` block? I thought that `tell` blocks were just for directing commands without direct parameters? Do they determine type scope as well? Or is there a command hidden somewhere here in the construction/execution of the object specifier that depends on getting sent to the `Application "Aperture"` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the core of your question correctly - because you have solved the practical part, screwy dereferencing, which is a bit of an old chestnut for applescripters - you must only use terminology inside the relevant tell blocks, so if your application (Aperture) supplies the terminology "keyword", you can't refer to "keyword" unless you are inside a `tell application "Aperture"` block.

OR if for some reason you want to use terminology from a given app without using a tell block, you can wrap your code like this:

```
using terms from application "Aperture"
  -- blah blah about 'keyword' and other Aperture terminology
end using terms from
```

Comment: 'using terms from' is typically used for attachable applications - i.e. those which can run scripts 'from the inside' usually indicated by the fact that they have their own script menu - BBEdit is a good example. When you run a script from BBEdit's own script menu, then BBEdit is the default tell target, so strictly speaking "tell application" is unnecessary for the script to run, however, you still need to tell the compiler where to find the terminology, so it can compile, hence the need for a using terms for block. They're also used to compile scripts for apps that aren't installed.

Comment: Thanks Brennan. I guess this is what you need to do when you're designing a language and you don't want an 'import' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript is rather funny like this unfortunately and often times it's hit or miss.  In this case `repeat with item in list`, item is a reference to the contents, not the contents itself.  Often times AppleScript will dereference this for you, but not always.  Typically I always use the `repeat with x from 1 to count` method to avoid this problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem. When I replace the `repeat with movie in Movies` with `repeat with movieind from 1 to movielen` and then `set movie to item movieind in Movies`, the loop is functionally identical. IOW, it still works when I comment out the bit of the loop with the `name of every keyword in movie` object specifier, and then I include the `name of every keyword in movie` object specifier, it still gives me the same error about the class/identifier confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**About scripting Aperture keywords**

Keyword scripting in Aperture 3 is quite unintuitive. Here's what Ive learned:

- A keyword's `id` is a string with the path from the keyword name up to its top-level parent, with each parent's name preceded by a tab.
- The value of the `parents` property is just the id without the name and, if the keyword is not at the top-level, the tab following the name.
- Keywords don't compare equal even if their  values are the same; in fact, `keyword 1 of animage != keyword 1 of anImage`.
- An image may have multiple keywords with the same name if they have different parents. However, the name will only appear once wherever the image's metadata is displayed.
- The way to add a keyword to `anImage` with name `aName` and parents `theParents` is `tell anImage to make new keyword with properties {name:aName, parents:theParents, id:aName&tab&theParents}`

See [my entry here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=144482#p144482) for a fuller explanation plus add and remove handlers.